# hadoop test - During MapReduce is running I turn off a datanote

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am testing hadoop version 2.6.2 in cluster with 3 computers = 2 datanodes/nodemanager and 1 namenode/resourcemanager. I started mapReduce example wordcount and during mapReduce processing/running I link off (disconnect the ethernet cable) of 1 datanode to test if another datanode keep the running the mapReduce process.

Then, when a link off the cable the mapreduce of wordcount application stop to running. For example if disconnect 1 datanode computer when the word count is in 20% map 0% reduce the process not continue, stay stoped with this value of map and reduce.

Any suggestion why happen this problem?

Comment: What is the replication factor for the data? Is it set to 1 or 3?

Comment: I lot pleasure talk with you Sr. Ballur.  The <name>dfs.replication</name> in hdfs-site.xml is set to 2.

Comment: Does your job finally exit? If yes, does it exit with some error? Or it gets stuck at some percent?

Comment: Mr. Ballur it stuck at some percent. Rarely some error but in majority stuck some percent

Comment: In the log yarn in booth datanode i see only one datanode consuming memory and computing and with some containers. The another datanode is run but without consuming memory or received some container during mapreduce. In web manager of yarn (port. 8088) the health of booth is ok and available to process jobs.

Comment: Mr. Ballur, I turned off after some percent of mapreduce. I not turned off datanote before run application. For example when Map reduce is run in half percent (50% map 50% reduce) I turn off a datanode.

Comment: Its possible that some of the data is present in that other Data Node. Since you have set replication factor to 2. Hence, when you turn off that Data Node, it is unable to read data from that Data Node

Comment: Yes, I will make test with 3 in factor replication. Next week I return to tell if resolved my problem. Thanks a lot Mr. Ballur.

Comment: Mr Ballur, I tested with 3 factor replication but still the job stuck  during map reduce process in my test . I dont know what do, I guess did some wrong configuration but I dont know what. it like as the parallelism computing doesn't works.

Comment: Are you trying to do the reliability testing for Hadoop? If one node goes down, what happens? For a smaller cluster like yours, it may not make sense to do these tests.

Comment: So, I am testing if hadoop has capacity keep do the map reduce if a node has some failure. This is a main objective of namenode and resourcemanager, if a datanode/nodemanager fail, the job can't stuck.

Comment: I understand. But, like I said, for a smaller cluster like yours (only 2 nodes), this experiment may not make sense.